How to upgrade to 24.04.1
Through a mis-click of my own, during a Boot-Repair, somehow I now have the makings of kernel for 24.04.1 on my Ubuntu 23.10 machine and the 'Software Updater' shows no upgrade available. I've tried sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade as well and that doesn't do it. I've tried to walk back the kernel using Ubuntu Mainline Kernel Installer app and that did put an older kernel available on my Grub screen but it hangs and doesn't boot. I installed kernel 6.5.0-44-generic which is supposed to be for 23.10. Should I try and even older kernel?
So, what's the best path to actually get the upgrade without formatting the drive?
EDIT: I see that upgrades to 24.04.1 have been disabled by Ubuntu for now so I'll wait. For the others that say I'm late, my info said EOL was on Aug. 31st and Sept. 6th isn't all that late in my mind considering this is a home PC and not an enterprise where it might be of greater concern. AND Ubuntu found a major bug in the 24.04.1 release so I think waiting was beneficial. Thanks though.

Upgrades to 24.04.1 are disabled right now due to a critical bug discovered after they were first enabled. https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-release/2024-September/006226.html

Please fresh install instead. It is less error prone

@guiverc I'm overruling you and the rest of the reviewers on this one, this is a known active issue and upgrades to 24.04.1 from any release are currently disabled so this applies for any request about "why can't I upgrade to 24.04.1" - regardless of 23.10 being present or not.  This same issue applies to 22.04 LTS and others.  Therefore, I am leaving this open because it's a current event and a major issue.

Upgrades to 24.04.1 from older releases are currently blocked due to a critical bug discovered during initial rollout and enabling of upgrades.
Refer to https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-release/2024-September/006226.html for details, but basically:

That's correct - the upgrade was disabled due to a critical bug in
ubuntu-release-upgrader in the way it's using the apt solver. This is
being worked on and as soon as this is fixed, we'll re-enable the
upgrades.
-- Utkarsh Gupta (Canonical)

Because of this critical bug (unspecified in the email), the upgrade track from older releases to 24.04.1 LTS is disabled.
As of this post it is not yet re-enabled and thus upgrades to 24.04 do not function, and even if you force it the bug still exists.
The Register has an article that explains a little more.
--
Note that it is my PERSONAL RECOMMENDATION that you do a clean install of 24.04.1 if you want to go to 24.04.1 LTS from older releases.  Even once they fix the issue, there are still issues that can sometimes pop up after you do an upgrade.
